# Deploying "Out of box" skills (calendar, todo, etc.) to Microsoft Virtual Assistant

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm trying to deploy the Microsoft Virtual Assistant template that is outlined here:

https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/index

I've completed the deployment of the bot using the scripts and it works fine when running it on the Bot Emulator. However, there are no skills linked to it and for the life of me I can't figure out how to deploy the prebuilt skills to the virtual assistant I made.

I'm currently running this for the C# version of the bot on Visual Studio 2019 community edition. This didn't seem to be so hard last year when I ran through the process. I believe the skills were already attached to the bot I deployed. Not sure what changed or if I'm just overlooking something obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Update: I've so far discovered that the Skills have been broken out of the virtual assistant template and are now separate solutions which have to be built and deployed to azure. the solutions for each skill are located in the GitHub project for the virtual assistant. Once they are in azure and published you can then direct your bot to the manifest file to add the skills. Hope this helps others. I've still not got the skills working 100%, but at least I can get the bot to see them.